# First Textbox in Tablix cell defeats CanGrow of other Textboxes if it spans page break

Tags: reporting-services, textbox, ssrs-2008, page-break

I'm having a problem with the way SSRS handles long text in Textboxes inside a Tablix when the first Textbox is broken by a page break. Here's the simplified setup:

---

1. Create a Tablix with a single cell.
2. Add a Rectangle to that cell.
3. Add 2 Textboxes to that Rectangle, one below the other.
4. Ensure CanGrow = True for both Textboxes.
5. Add data to each Textbox such that each one contains multiple lines and the first contains enough lines to force some of it's lines past the end of the page. It helps to set the Page height to something ridiculous like 1 inch for testing purposes.

---

*It's necessary to preview the report in Print Layout mode or export it to PDF* to see that all the lines in the first Textbox print, but the second Textbox only prints the first line. Taking enough lines out of the first Textbox to avoid splitting it across a page will allow the second Textbox to print all of its lines.

Am I missing something? Is there a way to get the Tablix to behave properly across page breaks? It's the Tablix because moving the Rectangle and Textboxes outside of the Tablix fixes the problem. I don't see a CanGrow or similar property on the Rectangle or Tablix. A workaround is to put each Textbox into its own Tablix row, but that's not ideal in my situation.

Comment: Couldn't you create multiple columns in the tablix, one for each textbox? (I haven't tested today, but I've created reports like this that have worked correctly.)

Comment: No, these Textboxes are one on top of another. As noted, one row per Textbox would work, but that's not ideal for my situation. My goal here is to better understand why SSRS is doing this to me and whether there is something I can do to change it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to reproduce the problem, but looks like there is an easy workaround:

If you nest a second rectangle in the first, and then nest the second text box within that rectangle, my pdf came out correctly. I tried this with BIDS 2008R2, 11x8.5 (landscape) pages.

Comment: For posterity: After implementing this solution, I still had a problem with a few lines of data spilling out of the Textbox and past the border of the Tablix. This I solved by adding a very short rectangle at the bottom of the Tablix cell. Kludgy, but functional.