# Why is the text truncating when I export a paginated report to pdf?

Tags: pdf, powerbi, powerbi-paginated-reports

I have been working on a paginated report via report builder/power bi. When previewing the report in report builder, everything looks fine. When I export to word format, everything looks fine.
When I export to PDF, any text that exceeds one line in the report gets truncated.

Sample images of the report are seen here: https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Developer/Paginated-Reports-gt-Text-Truncates-when-using-quot-Export-to/m-p/2178696#M32800

I want to mention that the "can grow" property was mentioned in other threads and it is turned on and works everywhere other than in PDF exporting from what I can see, so I am hoping someone else has seen this issue?

Edit: Further testing confirms that this only happens when the textbox is within a container and only with rectangles to break into multiple pages.The rectangle has 10 different textboxes of varying sizes and the ones at the top / first page grow properly while the text boxes on page 2 only expand to the size of the textbox.

Comment: What visuals are you using for displaying text?  Are you able to provide a sample report with dummy data showing the issue?

Comment: Appologies in the delay. To answer these questions. @DarylWenman-Bateson these are just text boxes on the report. They pull from a power bi datasource, which originated from sharepoint data. I tried making a sample report with just one of the fields cutting off and it seems the word wrap does work fine when exporting to pdf. Therefore I believe something to be wrong with the specific report that I am working from, although not quite sure what settings to check in this case.

Comment: Are any of your text boxes on the original report overlapping, causing a rendering issue.  Its going to be hard to identify the issue if its report implementation specific and cant be reproduced

Comment: I did find something very relevant to the truncation after some further testing. It turns out that the issue occurs only when the text box is part of a rectangle container. This rectangle has multiple text boxes in it and the ones towards the bottom overlap to page 2 of the pdf. Those textboxes do not grow to fit the size of the boxes. Perhaps there is a size limit behind rectangle containers?

Comment: As it turns out - this post introduces the exact problem I am experiencing and it has a workaround in it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12922665/first-textbox-in-tablix-cell-defeats-cangrow-of-other-textboxes-if-it-spans-page    -> not sure if this is a defect or not but I can get it to work using a 2nd rectangle container for now to hold page 2 items. Only problem now is the extra blank page I receive in pdf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using tablix with a rectangle wrapped around multiple textboxes that expand to multiple pages, adding a 2nd rectangle to encapsulate the page 2 items seems to prevent this from happening (no truncation on page two text box items).